# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'models' imported from D:\portfolio\сlevertec\app\server\src\database\postgres\index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, es6-modules, koa

How to add  auto imports to  my Koa app?

This path ***import { user} from 'models/index.js'*** is wrong  when I start  my app  but this path ***import { user} from '../../models/index.js'*** is ok. When I hover on 'models/index.js'
i see the path like  module ***"d:/portfolio/сlevertec/app/server/src/models/index"*** and can switch  that is  mean that the path is exist.

***the folder structure***:

```
- server/
  - src/
    - database/
       - postgres/
          - index.js
    - models/
       - index.js
       - User.js
  - jsconfig.json
  - package.json
```

***jsconfig.json*** in the root of the app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "checkJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "models/*": ["models/*"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

***src/database/postgres/index.js***

```
import { user} from 'models/index.js'
import sequelize from './instance.js'

const User = sequelize.define('User', user)
```

***src/models/index.js***

```
export { default as user } from './User.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) to define your subpath exports.

**package.json**

```json
"exports": {
  ".": "./src/index.js",
  "./*.js": "./src/*.js",
  "models/*.js": "./src/models/*.js"
}
```